# iOS - Unable to save image into custom folder, after deletion that custom folder from photos album

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary

I want to save an image into custom folder in **iPhone**. I have done it.

But I am facing a strange problem that **when I run my code it works fine. But when I delete that custom folder from iPhone, and then run my code again, the custom folder is not created.**

If I change the custom folder name in my code, then it's created with the new name. But I want to create same folder name even after user deletes that custom folder. I don't want to create another custom folder.

My Code:

```
@interface CameraVC () 
{

    ALAssetsLibrary* library;
    GPUImageStillCamera *videoCamera;

}

- (IBAction)clickPhotoBtn:(id)sender {
if (!isCameraPermissionAccessed) {
    [self showAccessDeinedMessage :@"Camera permission denied" withMessage:@"To enable, please go to settings and allow camera permission for this app."];
    return;
}
[videoCamera capturePhotoAsJPEGProcessedUpToFilter:filter withCompletionHandler:^(NSData *processedJPEG, NSError *error){
    if (error!=nil)
    {
        [self showErrorMessage:@"Unable to capture image" ];
        return ;
    }

    else {
         UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:processedJPEG];
        CGFloat zoomReciprocal = 1.0f /currentScale;
        CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(image.size.width * ((1.0f - zoomReciprocal) / 2.0f), image.size.height * ((1.0f - zoomReciprocal) / 2.0f));
        CGRect croppedRect = CGRectMake(offset.x, offset.y, image.size.width * zoomReciprocal, image.size.height * zoomReciprocal);
        CGImageRef croppedImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], croppedRect);
        UIImage *croppedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:croppedImageRef scale:[image scale] orientation:[image imageOrientation]];
        CGImageRelease(croppedImageRef);
        if (filterType == GPUIMAGE_GRAYSCALE && !isPhotoBlackAndWhite) {
        GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:croppedImage];
        GPUImageColorInvertFilter *stillImageFilter = [[GPUImageColorInvertFilter alloc] init];
        [stillImageSource addTarget:stillImageFilter];
        [stillImageFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
        [stillImageSource processImage];
        UIImage *currentFilteredVideoFrame = [stillImageFilter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];
            [self.library saveImage:currentFilteredVideoFrame toAlbum:@"myCustomFolder" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                if (error!=nil) {
                    [self showErrorMessage:@"Unable to save image in photos album, please ensure this app must has permission access to photos album to save images."];
                    return ;
                }
                else {

                    NSString *message = @"Image saved";
                    UIAlertView *toast = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                                    message:message
                                                                   delegate:nil
                                                          cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                          otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                    [toast show];
                    int duration = 1;
                    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, duration * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [toast dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
                    });
                }

            }];
}
```

Comment: how you saving and deleting image? that code required

Comment: @ Lion, I am saving image through above code, means capture image from camera and save to custom folder. And I am deleting complete that custom folder (not deleting images).

Comment: where is the code of saving image in that folder and deleting folder?

Comment: @ Lion, see method - (IBAction)clickPhotoBtn:(id)sender , and see this line *[self.library saveImage:currentFilteredVideoFrame toAlbum:@"myCustomFolder" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {* and I deleting custom folder by manually .

Comment: Are you saving image in photo library of ios ? or in documents directory ?

Comment: I am saving image in photo library of iPhone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111716/discussion-between-monu-singh-and-lion).

Comment: Refer my Answer if it is helpful..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37163476/alassetslibrary-addassetsgroupalbumwithname-is-not-working-on-ios-9/37269569#37269569